# Clone html - datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, clone

I have a problem with clone datepicker. My script don't work but I don't why. I try add next (clone) a part of form. Can you guys help me please? Thank you.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mart01/8947uhrc/10/

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
          <div id="cosponsors" style="padding:12px;">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Date</label>  
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <input name="date" id="datepicker" value="DD.MM.YYYY" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Your tip</label>  
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="textinput" name="tip" type="text" placeholder="win / lose" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          </div>
         </form>
        <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Next" />
```

Script:

```
 $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date(), // = today
    });
});


var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
     $('.addRow').click(function() {

         var copy = $("#cosponsors").clone(true).appendTo("#myForm");
         var cosponsorDivId = 'cosponsors_' + uniqueId;
         copy.attr('id', cosponsorDivId );




          var deleteLink = $("<a>delete</a>");
             deleteLink.appendTo(copy);
             deleteLink.click(function(){
                 copy.remove();
             });

             $('#myForm div:last').find('input').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_'+ uniqueId); 
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + '_'+ uniqueId); 

             });

             uniqueId++;  
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access of the datepicker with jquery/class (.) instead of that use the id (#)

class selector ->

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(), // = today
        });
    });
```

id selector ->

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(), // = today
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your Jquery code in $(document).ready() and then try executing it